# Is random sampling really random and what good is it? (with a specific problem)

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Recently our school conducted the final exam in which there's the following problem (the problem is translated from the original chinese version):

We select $n$ out of $m$ labelled items (labelled from $1$ to $m$) as the sample ($m>n$). First we determine the sampling interval, which is an integer $k\leq \dfrac{m}{n}$, and then we randomly pick an item labelled $1\leq i_0\leq k$ and choose the sample to be $i_0, i_0+k, \cdots, i_0 +(n-1)k$. According to this procedure, the probability of each item being selected into the sample (   $\quad$ ).

A. depends on $i_0$. $\quad$ B. depends on its label. $\quad$ C. is not necessarily equal to one another. $\quad$ D. is equal to one another.

First of all, the problem is unrigorous in its essence: the value of $k$ should be taken as $\left[\dfrac{m}{n}\right]$, otherwise the problem is almost meaningless.

The official answer given is D, but I doubt that when $n\nmid m$, the items with labels large enough ($nk\sim m$) have zero possibility of being selected. But my teacher tells us that its a recapitulation of **systematic sampling and that we should choose D at first glance just because of this**. What I wonder are:

- Is the problem (after adding the $k$ condition) really a systematic sampling problem?
- If my thoughts are correct, then when we use systematic sampling, should it always be that $n\mid m$? What if unfortunately $m$ is a prime? Why use this whole method then if it causes so much trouble?

Thanks in advance for any answer which could dispel my doubts!

---

upd: Thanks @lulu @Jeroen Boschma for the replies. It seems true indeed that some *large* numbers are naturally impossible to be selected. And thus I propose my further speculation (the previous questions can be seen as archived, here are new ones):

- Is this *systematic sampling* process meant to **decrease the randomized amount** by reducing the scope of numbers you're choosing from?
- And are there any researches or ideas on *good* ways of choosing $k$ while preserving both randomness and simplicity? (My current conjecture is taking $k\approx \sqrt{n}$ so that the *choosing-random-nubmers* part is scaled down by a moderate amount)

*Note: I'm not professional at probability, and maybe the question goes well more complicated into i.e., the process of picking random numbers. I'm simply avid for more insight on this seemingly commonplace prosess.*

Comment: There's no apparent issue with $\frac mn$ being a non-integer...it's only used as an upper bound.  As to any bias...well, I agree that the mechanism for choosing $k$ is not clear.  If $k$ is chosen uniformly in the range, then I could see where that would bias the system in favor of smaller numbers.  In any case, I suggest picking some small values and writing it all out.  Maybe try different definitions for $k$.

Comment: As to what good it is, well you want some randomized mechanism.  You want to take the human selector out of the process as much as possible....there are all kinds of unsuspected correlations and dependencies.  Small numerical effects shouldn't be a big deal in most large systems.  Of course, you can always use a random generator if you have a good one available.

Comment: As a quick trial, I took $m=100, n=17$. in that case, if we define $k=\lfloor \frac mn\rfloor$ as you suggest, we get $k=5$.  In that case, the biggest number you could possibly get in your sample is $5+16\times 5=85$, so I agree that, in general, this method is biased against the top numbers.

Comment: I wonder. Take $m=12$, $n=5$ then $k=2$, If you pick $i_o$=1 then you have the sequence ${1,3,5,7,9}$ and for $i_o$=2 you have the sequence ${2,4,6,8,10}$. But 11 and 12 are not in either sequence, so I'm in doubt too. It seems you can never select the last $\text{remainder(m/n)}$ samples.

Comment: I have no specific probabaility knowledge.... The design of the process seems to be chosen such that for every $i_0$ a sequence with equal length results. If you eliminate the upper limit $i_0+(n-1)k$ and keep selecting until no samples available, I think you should be OK. But it's a bit of guessing from my side regarding the topic of 'systematic sampling'.

Comment: @Jeroen Boschma Yeah, erasing the bound would be a solution if $n$ is not strictly restricted to only one value, for example randomly picking $3\sim 4$ out of $35$ students to hand in homework with $m=35, k=10$. Thus $k$ and $n$ are actually predetermined and maybe it could be called *modulous sapling*.

Comment: Whether a sequence is actually random cannot be detected. There are many tests for randomness , but a sequence pasing those tests need not be random and vice versa a not random sequence might pass many of those tests.

Comment: @JeroenBoschma Indeed if you "eliminate the upper limit" as you suggest, every object in the population has an equal probability of being sampled. But we lose some of the properties of a "random sample," such as the property that the expected value of the sample mean is the population mean. Try it with the population $(0,0,0,0,30)$ with $m=5$ and $n=2.$ The population mean is $6$ but the expected value of the sample mean is $5.$

Comment: The problem is fairly artificial in that it calls for a random number generator (to choose $i_0$) so, presumably, we could just use that generator to select the sample.  That said, it's a pretty simple process and the only problem seems to be the forsaken stub at the upper end.  If, as usual, $m$ is vastly greater than $n$ one could sensibly choose to ignore that issue.  If that is unacceptable, I'd use random number generator to get all the sample.